# Edit result of mongodb query replacing a part of string

Tags: string, mongodb, replace

I have a problem with mongodb.
I have a query and I want to replace a part of the string of a field with another string.

For example:
instead of {description: "Hi."} I want {description: "Hi!"}
Replacing the "." with "!"

I don't want to update the database, I only want to edit the output of the query.
And the problem is that I need to do this inside the query and I don't think it's possible.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it only with MapReduce:

```
var mapFunction = function() { 
  emit(this._id, this.description); 
  emit(this._id,  this.description); 
};

var reduceFunction = function(id, descriptions) { 
  return  descriptions[0].replace(/\./g,"!"); 
};

db.yourCollection.mapReduce(mapFunction,reduceFunction,{out:{inline:1}} );
```